# Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted

Tags: android, continuous-integration, android-sdk-tools, codeship

I need to integrate a continuous integration system in my Android project, I have seen that CodeShip is a good alternative so I have created and configured a project to compile my Android application using the following script:

```
# Install java 8
jdk_switcher home oraclejdk8
jdk_switcher use oraclejdk8
export JAVA8_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
export BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=23.0.3
export ANDROID_SDK=24
export ANDROID_SDK_REV=24.4.1
#
# Install android sdk
export SDK_TAR=android-sdk_r$ANDROID_SDK_REV-linux
wget "http://dl.google.com/android/$SDK_TAR.tgz"
tar xvzf "$SDK_TAR.tgz"
rm "$SDK_TAR.tgz"
export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/android-sdk-linux
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH"
(while sleep 3; do echo "y"; done) | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/android update sdk -u
echo "y" | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter tools,platform-tools,build-tools-$BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION > step1.log
echo "y" | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-android-m2repository,extra-android-support,extra-google-analytics_sdk_v2,extra-google-google_play_services_froyo,extra-google-google_play_services,extra-google-m2repository > step2.log
echo "y" | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter android-$ANDROID_SDK,sysimg-$ANDROID_SDK,addon-google_apis-google-$ANDROID_SDK > step3.log
#
# Setup gradle
touch local.properties
echo "sdk.dir=$ANDROID_HOME" >> local.properties
chmod u+x ./gradlew
#
# Build
./gradlew assembleDevelop
```

When I push my repository and launch the compilation the following error occurs during compilation:

```
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3 not accepted.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
 occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
build-tools;27.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3
To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

Using Android SDK: /home/rof/clone/android-sdk-linux

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s
```

In principle the lines `echo "and" | android update sdk --no-ui --all - filter tools, platform-tools, build-tools- $ BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION> step1.log` should solve this problem. Someone can tell me what is missing in my script to perform the compilation successfully.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Contact the CodeShip support so they may be can post here an answer.

Comment: CodeShip does not support Android dev environment with CodeShip Basic projects -- https://documentation.codeship.com/general/about/mobile-support/

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Drew, What platform would you recommend for Android CI with a free plan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your infrastructure provider (i.e. CodeShip ) doesn't provide support for that level of SDK build tool. Perhaps contacting them might help.

As for the people who got an Android based error while working on their own PC :-

Change directory to C:\Users\YOURPCNAME\tools\bin 
And over here run sdkmanager --licenses 
Accept the licenses and you'll be good to go