# Unity build error. [Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted. ]

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-emulator

After I carried out some commands below on terminal to test my unity app with android emulators. My Unity project started failing build over and over again due to the same error in the pics below. If there is anybody who are familiar with this issue, would you give me advice to address it?

The command I carried out on terminal

1, export PATH=$PATH:/Users/userName/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools

2, echo PATH=$PATH: /Users/userName/Library/Android/sdk

3, cd /Users/userName/Desktop/AppName.apk

4, adb install AppName.apk

The details of the error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kdCY.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7GLP.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52598897/failed-to-install-the-following-android-sdk-packages-as-some-licences-have-not-b)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For people who may face the same errors in the future,

The problem was there is no licences file in /Users/username/Desktop/2019.2.9f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/SDK.

So I copied the file from /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk and paste it to the unity directory above.

The errors was successfully addressed.

I wish nobody wasted their time anymore because of this error.

Comment: `/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.2.19f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/SDK/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses` also works

Answer (score 9):

If anyone else happens to run into this problem, and you are using Unity Hub, run the following command from Terminal.

```sh
$ find /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor -name "sdkmanager" -exec {} --licenses \;
```

This will find all of the installed SDKs and check that all licenses are accepted. If they aren't, you will be prompted to accept.

You can run the command again to double-check everything is 100%.

Comment: I had to copy the generated licences across as per @Kotaro's answer. Running sdkmanager generated some errors for me, I think due to one of them not being compatible with the installed version of Java.

Comment: Thanks! It's work on my Macbook M2 Pro

Answer (score 8):

Open command prompt as **admin** and run

{path_to_sdk_folder}/tools/bin/sdkmanager.bat --licenses

and accept all.

Answer (score 0):

Keep bumping into this now Unity manages the platforms, Android Studio then grumbles about it if you point Android Studio at the platforms location Unity is using.

On Windows the quick and dirty fix is to run Android Studio as administrator, it then does what it needs and you can then go back to running Android Studio normally.

Not sure what the effects are long term, but it appears to work for me. Especially as I am not using the platform that Android Studio is grumbling about.

However, clearly, this isn't a great solution as the SDK manager in Android Studio doesn't see the platforms Unity claims to have installed.

Answer (score 0):

On a Windows machine, you'll need to find your `sdkmanager.bat` for your current version of Unity. For you this location could be something like

```
C:\Program Files\Unity\<version>\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat
```

or

```
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\<version>\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat
```

Once you find this, you can execute it with the `--licenses` flag in Powershell or your shell of choice, like below. **Make sure that you run your shell as an administrator.**

```
.\sdkmanager.bat --licenses
```

You'll then be prompted to review any licenses that have yet to be accepted. Answering `y` to these will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Kotaro is right.

For people who may face the same errors in the future,

The problem was there is no licences file in /Users/username/Desktop/2019.2.9f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/SDK.

So I copied the file from /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk and paste it to the unity directory above.

The errors was successfully addressed.

I wish nobody wasted their time anymore because of this error.

Cant comment so :

This is correct but make sure you open CMD with admin privileges as it wont save the licenses!

Answer (score 0):

Still not working but made some progress:

```
/c/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.19f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/SDK/cmdline-tools/6.0/bin
$ ./sdkmanager.bat --licenses
```

No license error after that. But now I get:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':unityLibrary:mobilenotifications.androidlib:compileReleaseAidl'.
> Failed to install the following SDK components:
      platforms;android-33 Android SDK Platform 33
  The SDK directory is not writable (C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.19f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK)
```

Program files and not writable... I'm gonna try installing Unity from the hub but on another drive where I don't need "windows admin rights" to do stuff. Edit: It worked.

Answer (score 0):

I tried different things but in the end this is what helped me and my Unity 2022.3.18f1 was:

`{path_to_sdk_folder}/cmdline-tools/{version}/bin/sdkmanager.bat --licenses`

the devil is `cmdline-tools` instead of `tools` subfolder

Answer (score -1):

Go to *src* -> *flutter* -> *flutter* -> *flutter_console*
and type `flutter doctor --android-licenses`. Click `y`.